# How can I get a list of all pages that have a certain url structure?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages

I am currently trying to get a list of all pages (their links and titles) that have similar url structure as the current page where the function is being used.

For e.g. if the current page is 'www.example.com/fruits/sweet-fruits/mango', then the function should return a list of all pages that have '/fruits/sweet-fruits/' in their url.

However, I don't know how to proceed since everything I've tried so far only partially works. Was wondering if there's a straightforward way (or any way) to do this ? Here's what I've tried so far:

```
function get_list($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(),
        $atts,
        'fruit_pages'
    );

    $current_page_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    preg_match('/\/fruits\/[^\/]+\/?/', $current_page_url, $matches);
    $base_url_structure = $matches[0];

    $fruit_pages_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'pagename' => $base_url_structure, /* HERE I've tried 's' and 'name' instead of 'pagename'
                        but they search for either the content or the slug */
        )
    );

    if ($fruit_pages_query->have_posts()) {
        $output = '<ul>';
        while ($fruit_pages_query->have_posts()) {
            $fruit_pages_query->the_post();
            $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return $output;
    } else {
         return 'No pages found.';
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to get all child pages of sweet-fruits then use https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60292/wp-query-to-get-child-pages-of-current-page or https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_children/ where you need to pass parent page id to get the list https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_parent_id/

Comment: Hi @Snuffy , thanks for replying. However, these pages aren't using the parent child attributes. And there's a lot of of pages. Hence I'm looking for a way to do this with the URL.